# Angular 4 Handle Error and continue the click action

Tags: angular

I need to click a button to submit my data to api server. At the same time, I need to check whether the token is expired? If it is expired, the system will auto refresh a new token and store into localstorage.

The way I check the expired token and auto renew a token which is :

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
    constructor(private injector: Injector, private loginService: LoginService) {}

handleError(error) {
    if (error.rejection.status === 401 || error.rejection.status === 403) {
      this.loginService.postLogin(localStorage.getItem('user_email'), localStorage.getItem('password')).subscribe(res => {
          if (res.access_token) {
            localStorage.setItem('access_token', res.access_token);
          } else if (res.error) {
            this.injector.get(Router).navigate(['/login']);
          }
        }, () => {
        this.injector.get(Router).navigate(['/login']);
        },
      );
    }
    throw error;
  }
}
```

So now the question is that I click the button and it check the expired token and refresh successfully but I need to click the button again. Is there any way that I can continue the action without click the button again?

Comment: I don't understand, where token refresh is happening..

Comment: Just call the function for action just after setting token in the localstorage instead of calling again on click

Comment: actually my way is to re-login and get the new token

Comment: do you have the data property when will the token expires? if yes, did you save it in the storage? if yes then how can we access it?

Answer (score 0):

The way i solved this:
- Create a wrapper class for rest calls. Mine is called AuthService.
- Instead of calling httpclient.get, i call authservice.get (which in it's own turn calls httpclient.get after checking authorization)

authservice contains a method 'checkAuth' which checks if the user is logged in and returns some callbacks. The general idea is to pass along callbacks.

pseudo-code (maybe):

```
// Component
click() {
    this.authService.get('').subscribe(data => console.log('yay'))
}

// AuthService
get(url: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.checkAuth(function() {
        return this.http.get(url)
    }
}

// AuthService checkAuth
checkAuth(callback: any): Observable<any> {
    return new Observable(observer => {
        this.isLoggedIn().subscribe(success => {
            if (success) {
                callback().subscribe(response => {
                    observer.next(response);
                }, error => {
                    observer.error(error);
                });
            }
        }
    }
}

// AuthService isLoggedIn
isLoggedIn(): Observable<boolean> {
    return new Observable(observer => {
        // Check your authorization and refresh if needed
        if (localStorage bla bla) {
             this.http.post(refresh etc.etc.)
        }

        // Do whatever and call observer.next(true || false) or observer.error() depending how you handle the isLoggedIn Observable
    }
}
```

I hope you get the idea

Answer (score 0):

You could use interceptors to check whether your token is expired or not.

If the interceptor retrieves a login error from your backend then use a BehaviourSubject to renew your token and keep the rest of the requests paused until you get logged in again.

With this method you avoid pressing the button multiple times and the user won't know what's going on under the hood.

Also I can't comment, that's why I'm adding this as an answer.